# String characters count compatability with iOS7

Tags: ios, swift2

Using Swift 2, for a project that supports iOS 7 and later.

I am trying to find the count of characters in a String, by using `string.characters.count`. However in the *Quick Help Inspector*, it shows the availability as **iOS (9.0 and later)**.

I have used this method on an iPad with iOS 8.4 installed on it and it did not give any errors, and gave me the correct length of the string.

What would happen if I were to use it on a device with iOS 7 installed on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Quick Help Inspector* gives a confusing information.

`string.characters.count` is dependent of the **Swift version**, not of the iOS version.

As long as you're using Swift 2+, `string.characters.count` will be available, independently of the OS.

Comment: Moreover, anything from the Swift Standard Library gets included it your app when you build, so its availability is based on the Xcode version you build with, not the OS versions you deploy to. (At least for now. Apple has said that someday Swift will solidify to where the standard library can be a system shared library, at which point it won't get bundled in your app anymore.)