# How can I determine whether a property or function in Swift 3 is available for iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

For example, in swift 3 there is a new type and property: `Calendar.current`, does it support for iOS 8?

The document said the SDK is iOS 10+, but I can run a app using this type property on iOS 8 device. This is very strange.

I want to know is there any place to check the minimum iOS version support for a type, property and function?

Or may be just the document is not updated? I use Xcode 8 GM version.

Comment: Swift syntax != platform availability. `Calendar.current` is available wherever Swift 3 and Foundation are available, independently of the platform and its version.

Comment: @EricAya how can I tell a syntax or no syntax difference? Because in the doc, some function shows "Availability: iOS (2.0 and later), tvOS (2.0 and later)", but for `static var current: Calendar { get }`, it shows "Availability : iOS (10.0 and later), macOS (10.12 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later), watchOS (3.0 and later)", but actually available for iOS 8.

Comment: Xcode's Quick Help Inspector and some docs are plain wrong about this.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36249701/2227743

Answer (score 0):

The Swift Syntax that is available is dependant on the development environment (The version of Xcode), not the iOS platform that Xcode is building for. Therefore swift 3.0 syntax will be valid for any project for any iOS version that is built using Xcode 8+ (assuming you have not enabled the setting to use legacy swift, which uses the older syntax)

Answer (score 0):

As @Eric Aya said, just because it's new for Swift 3 doesn't mean that it won't work on earlier versions of iOS.

This is (somewhat) equivalent to the change of `CGRectMake()` to `CGRect()`. You can't use `CGRectMake()` in Swift 3, but its replacement will work for pre iOS 10 (how else would you do it?).

Swift 3 will work for any project being made in Xcode 8 (unless you specifically choose Swift 2). It does not take into account which version of iOS or which device.

You can read more at the [official Swift 3 migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/).

Comment: In the doc, some functions show "Availability: iOS (2.0 and later), tvOS (2.0 and later)", but for `static var current: Calendar { get }`, it shows "Availability : iOS (10.0 and later), macOS (10.12 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later), watchOS (3.0 and later)", but actually available for iOS 8. How can I check the availability of a function in the doc?